# Offsetting a table of contents in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a React + tailwind page in which i have created a table of contents which on clicking takes you to the mapped part of the webpage.
The problem is that I also have a sticky header of 100px length, so whenever you click on(lets say you click on no.3 in table, it takes you to part3 of main article) but it gets hidden/overshadowed by header (header has a z index of 20).

What can I do so that when clicked, table should display the required section below header?

```
<ol className="list-decimal pl-5">
    {blogOne[0].tableList.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <li
              key={index}
              className={`${index === selectedIndex ? "text-blue-500 font-Bold" : ""} py-2`}
             >
               {index === selectedIndex ? (
                 <Link
                   className="text-blue-500font-guruWayBold"
                   href={`#${item.id}`}
                   onClick={() => setSelectedIndex(index)}
                 >
                   {item.title}
                 </Link>
                ) : (
                  <Link
                    className=""
                    href={`#${item.id}`}
                    onClick={() => setSelectedIndex(index)}
                  >
                    {item.title}
                  </Link>
                )}
            </li>
        );
    })}
</ol>
```

Comment: You can use [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider applying [`scroll-padding-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding-top) to the scroll container (such as the `<html>` element) equal to the height of the sticky header element.

In your case, you stated your sticky header element is `100px` height, so you could apply `scroll-padding-top: 100px` to the `<html>` element of the document by adding the Tailwind utility class `scroll-pt-[100px]` to the `<html>` element:

```js
function App() {
  const blogOne = [
   {
     tableList: [
       { id: 'foo', title: 'Foo' },  
       { id: 'bar', title: 'Bar' }, 
       { id: 'baz', title: 'Baz' }, 
     ],
   },
  ];
  
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState();

  return (
    <ol className="list-decimal pl-5">
      {blogOne[0].tableList.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <li
            key={index}
            className={`${index === selectedIndex ? "text-blue-500 font-Bold" : ""} py-2`}
          >
            {index === selectedIndex ? (
              <a
                className="text-blue-500font-guruWayBold"
                href={`#${item.id}`}
                onClick={() => setSelectedIndex(index)}
              >
                {item.title}
              </a>
            ) : (
              <a
                className=""
                href={`#${item.id}`}
                onClick={() => setSelectedIndex(index)}
              >
                {item.title}
              </a>
            )}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ol>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<html class="scroll-pt-[100px]">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

  <div class="sticky top-0 h-[100px] bg-red-200">Sticky header</div>

  <div id="app"></div>

  <div id="foo" class="h-screen bg-green-200">
    Foo
  </div>

  <div id="bar" class="h-screen bg-blue-200">
    Bar
  </div>

  <div id="baz" class="h-screen bg-yellow-200">
    Baz
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: The table of content and the articles both are in seperate divs

Comment: That shouldn't have any effect on the solution described.